# docker daemon не запускается

Tags: ubuntu, docker

```
toor@pccp:~$ sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                          [ OK ]
```

и все же

```
toor@pccp:~$ sudo service docker status
 * Docker is not running
```

```
toor@pccp:~$ sudo docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. 
Is the docker daemon running?
```

как такое может быть?

Comment: еше заметил что после ``` sudo service docker restart ```  на нескольно секунд он работает, потом снова останавливается

Comment: Странно что вы до сих пор не посмотрели логи, там все видно. Если по какой то причине не видно или не получается понять как именно, тогда попробуйте запустить демон докера не через systemd, а "напрямую"  `sudo dockerd`
Наверняка что то прояснит.

Comment: это wsl ubuntu и проблема была в правах администратора винды

Comment: Моя слеза стекает и всхлип застряет где-то между радостью и печалью.